# How to set default value to login password text box in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I want to set a default value to my `Login` control. This is my `Login` control in template mode :

```
    <td align="center" dir="rtl" style="width: 140px; padding-bottom: 20px;">
        <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" CssClass="txtbox " Font-Size="0.8em" 
            Height="24px" Width="137px" Text="<%$ Resources:resource, username%>  " 
            Font-Names="tahoma" AutoCompleteType="FirstName" MaxLength="32"> 
        </asp:TextBox>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center" dir="rtl" style="width: 160px">
        <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server"  CssClass="txtbox" Font-Size="0.8em" 
            Height="24px" Width="137px" Font-Names="tahoma" 
            TextMode="Password" MaxLength="32"   >
        </asp:TextBox>
```

When I tried to set the default value to password box, it doesn't appear.
I can't access the password box from code behind page.
What shoud I do?

Comment: Why you want to do this? I want to know the use of setting default password on page in which way it is helpful to you?

Answer (score 5):

set the attribute instead of .Text property , as password mode is made to not store the sensitive information , this is the workout

```
txtPassword.Attributes.Add("value", "defaultpassword")
```

But I will not prefer this way as this will emit the password to client and they can see it.

better way would be let it be blank and not made it Mandatory , later show user a message to keep the password field blank for default password.

In the code behind check if password text box is empty pass the default password instead of textbox value.

For login button click event, your code behind should look something like :

```
 string password = (txtPassword.Text == String.Empty)? DefaultPassword : txtPassword.Text;
 AuthenticateUser(txtUserName.Text,password);
```

Answer (score 4):

The right way to assign value to textbox with textmode ="password" is by code behind :

```
textbox.Attributes.Add("value", "whatever")
```

Answer (score 2):

You might find [this](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/12/18/1300.aspx) useful. Talks about how to set the Value of a TextBox with TextMode=Password.